# JSFUnit without Maven and JBoss AS

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jsf-2, jsfunit

I would like to use JSFUnit for testing our web app. But we are using weblogic server and build process doesn't use maven. All of the examples use maven to run the tests. Is there other way to run JSFUnit tests without maven and JBoss ?

Any link or lead in this direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently they do not support WebLogic server. The only supported containers at present are these
http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e713

But still you can try for WebLogic. Refer to this reply from Stan who is the project Lead for JSFUnit
http://community.jboss.org/message/70691#70691

If not maven or ant, you can just run through the browser.
Tutorial: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=215
If using servlet 3.0 container see this,
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJSFUnitwithServlet30

But unfortunately, you might have to stick to Cargo/Cactus based testing with JUnit 3. JSFUnit works well with basic/form authentication and even Spring Security. But I faced lot of problems with when using Spring Security with CAS authentication and never got it to work.